# Diesel compilation hangs on Lightsail

Tags: linux, rust, amazon-lightsail, rust-diesel

I'm trying to deploy a database-backed Rust app on Amazon Lightsail.  It uses the ORM crate Diesel.  It compiles without trouble on my local (Arch) Linux machine.

To compile the app remotely, I SSH into a Lightsail Debian VM.  After installing Rust, cloning the repo, and specifying the toolchain, I run `cargo build`.  This does compile a bunch of crates, but in compiling Diesel it appears to hang.  At least, calling `ps` shows the cargo and rustc processes appearing to continue after 30 mins.

I've tried Diesel versions 1.4.5 and 2.0.0, stable and nightly Rust toolchains, and Ubuntu as well as Debian VMs.

[Edit: the app also compiles without trouble on a Linode VM.]

What could be the problem?  (How can I collect further information for diagnosis?)

Comment: Isn't Diesel one of those ORMs that need to connect to a database to introspect and then compile? http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/#:~:text=We%20need%20to%20tell%20Diesel%20where%20to%20find%20our%20database.

Comment: Diesel does not require a database to inspect at compile time. This feature is separated (as in separate command) from the actual compilation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the CPU graph showing?

Lightsail uses burstable instances that have a baseline of CPU and can handle occasional traffic spikes, but if you spike the CPU for too long then the CPU gets throttled.

If you check on the instances metrics tab you can see if it's running out of burst capacity (choose burst capacity percentage or minutes from the drop down).

Comment: That’s a good point.  So far as I can tell, the compilation doesn’t consume significant burst capacity (console shows it to remain above 70% throughout).

Comment: how long would you expect this build to take? Depending on your instance size you could have less than 2 hours in the burstable zone at 70%.

Comment: at least on my laptop, the whole ("release") build with 165 crates takes around 3 minutes; the diesel crate takes not very much of this (perhaps 5 seconds).